# Do we ever hear the Romulan language being spoken?

Tags: star-trek, romulan

In *Star Trek* we occasionally hear alien languages being spoken, notably Klingon every now and again, and Vulcan features infrequently.  The third major alien species that features regularly is the Romulans; I don't recall hearing it, but do we ever hear their language being spoken?

Comment: It's possible that *TNG*-era writers were a little more shy to include Romulan words than Klingon ones, because Klingon had a full dictionary to refer to, but Romulan would require some making up on the spot.

Comment: @Praxis - I find that hard to believe, since the fifth TNG episode featured Ferengi speaking in their native language.

Comment: @T.E.D. Romulans and Klingons were pre-established characters, Ferengi were not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

The [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_language) page provides a small list of phrases and words that we hear or see in the franchise:

> - D'deridex: "Warbird", a term designating Romulan starships, or perhaps a particular class of starship (heard several times in TNG)
> - Jolan Tru: A salutation, used in the same way as "greetings" and "good-bye".    (TNG: "Unification I", ENT: "United")
> - Prod: Praetor or Commander. (Star Trek 2009)
> - Uhlan: A rank in the Romulan military. (TNG: "The Defector")
> - Veruul: A churlish or rude person; possibly profane (TNG: "The Defector")
> - Viinerine: A type of food. (TNG: "Face of the Enemy")
> - Vorta Vor: The source of all creation. (Star Trek V: The Final    Frontier)

In terms of seeing the script, we see the following script on Geordi's VISOR in TNG: *The Mind's Eye*:

[image: Romulan script]

There is also quite a far more extensive understanding of the language provided on [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Romulan_language), but these are outside the scope of the question (which refers to language heard *on-screen*)

Comment: 'D'deridex: "Warbird"' - this one is somewhat questionable, given that [various types of ships called "Warbird" appeared during the ages](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Warbird) (even if we discount the Klingon ones that were probably mix-ups with the term "Bird of Prey"), and that MA page also says: "a warbird of a much earlier design than that of the D'deridex-class", implying that not all "warbirds" belong to the D'deridex class.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I hadn't actually considered that point, but now that you bring it up I'll make the changes ;)

Comment: An [uhlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uhlan) is actually a type of light cavalry soldier.  Not sure exactly how that relates to the Romulan military rank, if at all.

Answer (score 5):

There was [an episode of Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Minefield_(episode)) where they first encounter Romulans and before the ship's computer can render a translation, you only hear Romulan. This is what is heard (from Memory Alpha):

```
Uhn kan'aganna! Tehca zuhn ruga'noktan! 
Uhn Kan'aganna! Tehca zuhn! Neemasta kan'aganna uckwazta! 
Kuhn'ukchtacht zuhn vockwadai! 
Bar'ak t'stu annankana.
```

Comment: Could you find what the episode was?

Comment: It was almost certainly _Minefield_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit most likely. I've three episodes into the last season, and thus far, Minefield was the only one with Romulans

Comment: @Petersaber: This is one of those occasions in which making global probability statements based on a truncated sample is shown to be a logical fallacy. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just Googled it. Hah. Romulans suddenly make a few appereances (4!) in season 4, after appearing only once in previous 3 seasons. Oh well :D

Comment: @Petersaber: :P The fourth season overall was very fond of revisiting old classic Star Trek races thanks to the influence of new showrunner Manny Coto, and did so (IMO) very effectively.